# Update to/install latest Flutter packages (pubspec.yaml)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, package

I want to install latest Flutter packages in my android studio project.

In npm, `npm install <package name>` installs latest packages automatically and `npm update` updates all packages automatically.

Is there any way to do this in Flutter?

Answer (score 10):

Let's say you have these packages in your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
dependencies:
  foo: ^1.0.0
  bar: ^5.0.0
```

And at some point in future there is an update available for both of them, and you decide to run

```
flutter pub outdated
```

It would now list something like:

```
Dependencies            Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest
foo                     1.0.0    1.2.0       1.2.0       1.2.0
bar                     5.0.0    5.3.0       6.0.0       6.0.0
```

You see there is no breaking change for `foo`, since it is still on `1.x.x`, however, `bar` has got a breaking change, it has been updated from `5.x.x` to `6.x.x`. So what should you do now?

1. If you safely want to update the packages without breaking your code, run

   ```
   flutter pub upgrade
   ```

   This would now create `pubspec.lock` file with

   ```
   packages:
     foo:
       version: "1.2.0"
     bar:
       version: "5.3.0"
   ```
2. If you want to update both of them to the latest version, you'll have to manually do it in `pubspec.yaml` file by specifying (`foo` won't need manual version):

   ```
   dependencies:
     bar: ^6.0.0
   ```

   This would create `pubspec.lock` file with

   ```
   packages:
     foo:
       version: "1.2.0"
     bar:
       version: "6.0.0"
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Yes it is possible to update existing packages. Use the flutter command below:

`flutter pub outdated`

This was introduced in Dart 2.8:

> As of Dart 2.8, you can use `pub outdated`, a new tool for automatically determining which of your dependencies need to be updated to the latest and greatest versions.

Answer (score 9):

With a release of **Flutter 2.0** you can now upgrade flutter dependency packages automatically using these below command lines:

1. `flutter pub outdated`
2. `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

Answer (score 1):

You can check version is out dated or not using **flutter pub outdated** command.

in output you will get all outdated versions.

Output:

```
Dependencies                           Current    Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest    
carousel_pro                           *0.0.13    *0.0.13     1.0.0       1.0.0     
firebase_auth                          *0.15.4    *0.15.5+3   0.16.0      0.16.0
```

Here, current version show, which you are using and latest show which package version is available.

**Note:** You have to specify latest version in pubspec.yaml file and then you have to run.

```
flutter pub get
```