# Flutter - v 1.24.0 to 2.0.5 - pubspec.yaml version problems

Tags: flutter, version

I have downloaded flutter_windows_2.0.5-stable.zip and installed Flutter 2.0.5.

When I run a v1.24.0 project, I get the following output:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in get_json ...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.0-29.10.beta.
Because flutter_easyloading 3.0.0 requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0 and no versions of flutter_easyloading match >3.0.0 <4.0.0, flutter_easyloading ^3.0.0 is forbidden.
So, because get_json depends on flutter_easyloading ^3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because get_json depends on flutter_easyloading ^3.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

Contents of pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.12.2
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0 #^4.0.1
  rflutter_alert:  ^1.1.0 #^2.0.2
  pdf_flutter: ^1.1.4
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^18.4.49-beta
  webview_flutter:  ^1.0.7 #^2.0.4
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^2.0.0 #^4.1.1
```

Looking around the Internet I found
[Update to/install latest Flutter packages (pubspec.yaml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708170/update-to-install-latest-flutter-packages-pubspec-yaml)

At the end of this it is stated that in Flutter 2 it will help to run
1 flutter pub outdated and
2 flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

Running 1 "flutter pub outdated" gives a looot of output and ends with:

```
Changed 75 dependencies!
25 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
No changes to pubspec.yaml!
```

Running 2 "flutter pub upgrade --major-versions" also gives a lot of output and ends with:

```
...
No dependencies changed.
25 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
Changed 4 constraints in pubspec.yaml:
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0 -> ^4.0.1
  rflutter_alert: ^1.1.0 -> ^2.0.2
  webview_flutter: ^1.0.7 -> ^2.0.4
  json_serializable: ^2.0.0 -> ^4.1.1
```

pubspec.yaml was changed to:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.12.2
  json_annotation: ^4.0.1 #^4.0.1
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.2 #^2.0.2
  pdf_flutter: ^1.1.4
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^18.4.49-beta
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.4 #^2.0.4
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^4.1.1 #^4.1.1
```

Now I try run my (old) project again which results in the following output:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in get_json...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.0-29.10.beta.
Because no versions of json_serializable match >4.1.1 <5.0.0 and json_serializable 4.1.1 requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, json_serializable ^4.1.1 is forbidden.
So, because get_json depends on json_serializable ^4.1.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because get_json depends on json_serializable ^4.1.1, version solving failed.)
```

I have tried many variations of what is described above, but I am stuck.

Can anyone help or guide me in the right direction? Thank you.

==============================

Thank you to Ujjwal Raijada. I got Flutter 2 because of web support and did not think of null safety. However, I have now followed the migration guide to the detail and now have the following pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.13.1
  json_annotation: ^4.0.1
  rflutter_alert: ^2.0.2
  #pdf_flutter: ^1.1.4 # Package pdf_flutter is not null safe and therefore cannot be used ...
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^19.1.57-beta
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.4
  flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.0.1
  json_serializable: ^4.1.1
```

I have also changed my code as suggested by the migration guide. so now I run "flutter packages pub run build_runner build" which results in:

```
The pubspec.yaml file has changed since the pubspec.lock file was generated, please run "pub get" again.
pub finished with exit code 65
```

Pressing "pub get" in pubspec.yaml gives the following result:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.0-29.10.beta.
Because get_json requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because get_json requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

What should I do now? Any help out there? Thank you.

Comment: you need to upgrade your sdk.

Comment: to upgrade, you can check this youtube video by flutter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvq7wbn4VAA&t=193s

Comment: Thank you to Ujjwal Raijada. I have upgraded/migrated as explained in the link. There are still problems. I have expanded my question above with the results  (after the ===... line).

Comment: try updating dart

Comment: I have installed an update to the emulator and an update to the Dart plugin. It works now. I did nothing else and it did not work the first time I tried. Apparently, some configuration has also been changed. So I am back on the track and now runs Flutter 2.0.5 and Dart 2.12.3. Thanks for the help. Closing the ticket.